# How to properly link two Maven projects?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have two projects:

1. Project-Core
2. Project-Source

Project-Core POM.xml:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>2.1</version>
```

Project-Source POM.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>pom</type> (have tried leaving it out)
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've done **mvn clean install** on Project-core, which installed the artifact in the local maven repository.

I am able to CD to Project-source and use **mvn clean install** (this installs Project-Source in the local maven repo as well), but I'm having trouble with NetBeans not finding the classes I need (from Project-Core) inside Project-Source.

What's a proper way of linking multiple projects? Since Project-Core produces a jar and that jar is installed in the local repository, it looks logical to only have to list that jar as a dependency on my Project-Source project. Is anything else needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified that the dependency "project-core" is of type "pom", but from the declaration it has packaging "jar" ?
Try:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

Edit:

I've created a simple test project which worked just fine to use in Netbeand 7.0.1. Take a look and see if it gives you any hints.[Code snippet](https://gist.github.com/1779486)

Comment: Indeed, I had tried leaving out the <type>, but installing from cli didn't work. It only seemed to work after adding <type>pom</type>. It's either sporadic, or I'm missing something, because **install** seems to work either way now.

Comment: What is your project layout? Could you post some more information regarding your project?

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing much I can think of. Just that my **core** project is installed, it's listed as a dependency in my **source** project pom.xml, yet I can't see its classes.

Do I need a parent pom for these two projects?

Comment: Thanks for your time! do I need to have the same POM parent for both projects? I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks again, after setting up a parent pom and listing my two projects as modules, it appears to be working (as in I now have a different error).

Comment: Nice! Post the problem if you need any more help with the new problem then. Good luck!